# Django - subclassing UserAdmin to create dynamic templates?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm not quite sure how to phrase the question that I want to ask.  Let's say that you have two profile objects that could possibly be associated with a User.  Only one of them will be associate (there's a one to one mapping) but it could be one of two possible profile objects.  My admin code looks like this:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)

class AProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfileA

class BProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfileB

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [AProfileInline, BProfileInline, ]

admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

This works ok, but of course it displays unnecessary information. It would be nice if the admin page would only display the proper inline.  I imagine this is complicated and probably is a problem if, for example, I want to change from one profile type to another.  Any thoughts?

Comment: So how would you handle a new user?  Does something external automatically create a default profile of one type or the other?  How would you change a user's profile from one type to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it.  Keep in mind, **this is a hack**.  I based this code off of the `ModelAdmin` code in `django.contrib.admin.options`.

```
admin.site.unregister(User)

class AProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfileA

class BProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfileB

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [AProfileInline, BProfileInline, ]

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(UserProfileAdmin, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if obj:
            self.inline_instances = []
            if AProfileInline.model.objects.filter(user=obj):
                inline_instance = AProfileInline(self.model, self.admin_site)
                self.inline_instances.append(inline_instance) 
            if BProfileInline.model.objects.filter(user=obj):
                inline_instance = BProfileInline(self.model, self.admin_site)
                self.inline_instances.append(inline_instance)
        return obj

admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

This solution assumes that both `UserProfileA` and `UserProfileB` have foreign key relations to `User` through a field called `user`.

The `change_view` and `delete_view` functions call `get_object`, so this code should properly replace the inline form instances before these views are rendered.

This code overrides `get_object` to perform the following extra actions:

1. The inline forms are empty by default (for pre-existing objects)
2. If a `UserProfileA` is found that references the current `User` (through the `user` field), an inline form for `UserProfileA` is added.
3. If a `UserProfileB` is found that references the current `User` (through the `user` field), an inline form for `UserProfileB` is added.

Quirks of this solution:

- `UserProfileAdmin.__init__` will still create a default version of `self.inline_instances` which will then be overwritten whenever `change_view` or `delete_view` are used.
- This function was never meant to do what the above code is using it for.  If `UserProfileAdmin.get_object` is called in any other code, the inline forms will be needlessly recalculated.

Comment: You don't need to say `if AProfileInline.model.objects.filter(user=obj).count():`; you could just say `if AProfileInline.model.objects.filter(user=obj):`.